Halachic Restraining order?
Did Chazal outline parameters for halachic restraining orders?
Are there examples of the Rishonim addressing, utilizing this?

They could beat up a person, stop beating him, wait for him to swear that he won't go within 1000 amot of a person, and resume beating him if he doesn't.

For those who think @ClintEastwood is joking, he’s absolutely correct. That’s how they used to enforce policies, and how they’d get people to sign something. It’s even practiced in some places today, usually to help a woman get a halachic divorce from her husband.

Thank you! Sources please?
